# Jenkins and Github auto trigger

Tags: github, jenkins, continuous-integration, localhost

I'm trying to setup Jenkins and Github such that Jenkins will build my project when something is pushed to Github. However, I can't seem to get the webhooks to work. I set the webhook on github to : http://localhost:8080/github-webhook/. I'm running the jenkins server on my laptop, therefore I am using 'localhost'. There might also be an error with this url, as github does say: 'Invalid host'?

I've tried to find some good guides, but none seem to be updated nor mention how to set it up locally. So any help would really be appreciated!

[image: First screen]

[image: Second screen]

Comment: here is a guide i have used in the past for this, http://fourword.fourkitchens.com/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This cannot work. *localhost* maps to the IP address 127.0.0.1, which is just the same machine. So while you can access your local Jenkins installation via *localhost*, the GitHub server cannot.

You will either need a static IP address or you need to map a DNS entry to your dynamic IP (for example with http://www.dnsdynamic.org). And you need to open the port 8080 for external access. Only then will GitHub be able to reach your local instance with its webhook.