# Run Jenkins job on Github Push

Tags: git, github, jenkins

I know this question is asked several times and gone through the answers too, still none of them is working for me.

I am following [Setting up a github webhook in jenkins](http://thepracticalsysadmin.com/setting-up-a-github-webhook-in-jenkins/)
 and tried to run `Jenkins` job build on `Github` push.

But after adding **`Jenkins hook url`** in **`Services / Manage Jenkins (GitHub plugin)`**, marking as **`Active`** then on **`Update Service`** when I clicked on **`Test service`** button, I always get the message:

> Okay, the test payload is on its way.

I also tried pushing change in Github repository but job didn't run, Then I went back to Services Section then there is a red warning symbol with message **"Last delivery was not successful. Service Timeout"**.

Can you please help me in fixing the issue?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because my Jenkins is **configured to localhost**, so referring `http://127.0.0.1:9999/github-webhook/`  in **`Jenkins hook url`** will not work as the Github servers will not be able to reach the Jenkins server to trigger the build. More can be read from here:
[Jenkins Build trigger on Github push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28732873/jenkins-and-github-auto-trigger)